# Why am I getting "TypeError: 'x' is read-only" error without problems with 'use strict' or 'constant'?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, constants, typeerror

I'm getting the error the following error in the debugger. I believe it to be an issue with what the shuffle() function is calling in line 230 (marked in the 2nd block code) and how the arrays are set up. Maybe a new way to set up these arrays would fix my issues.

**ERROR:**

> Paused on exception
>
> TypeError: 229 is read-only

**main.js**

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  
    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex != 0) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element.
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
  
    return array;
  }

function loadImageArray(category, abbreviation) {
    let list = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        list[list.length] = "./faces/" + category + "/" + abbreviation + i + ".JPG";
    }

    return list;
}

//grabs localStorage array if it exists, else creates face array and saves
function fetchArray(key, category, abbreviation){
    let data = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem(key) != null){
        data = localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    else {
        data = loadImageArray(category, abbreviation);
        localStorage.setItem(key, data);
    }
    return data;
}

//saves localStorage face arrays with key
function setArray(key, array) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, array);
}

let faceAfraid = fetchArray("faceAfraid", "afraid", "AF");

const randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
let emotionsArray = [faceAfraid];
for (let i = 0; i < emotionsArray.length; i++){
    //shuffle(emotionsArray[i]);
    if (randomEmotion == i && emotionsArray[randomEmotion][randomImage] != null){
        document.getElementById("faceImg").innerHTML = "<img src = '" + emotionsArray[i][randomImage] +"' class='emotionImg' alt='face'></img>";
        emotionsArray[i].splice(i, 1);
        setArray(""+emotionsArray[i],emotionsArray[i]);
    }
}
```

**face.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        
        <title>ReTER Application</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="dark" id="face">
        <div id="faceImg" class="emotionImg">
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I've looked up [mdn web docs' explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only) for this, but that didn't seem to explain my issue because I do not use `'use strict';` anywhere in my JavaScript file.

I have commented out line 230 and it stops on line 234 with a secondary error

> Paused on exception
>
> TypeError: emotionsArray[i].splice is not a function

Commenting out that line 230 and 234 removes all debugging errors, but it only displays the alt text for my image. I would also like to point out that I'm aware `.innerHTML` is not the preferred way to do this, but it was not causing me issues before I changed the way the face arrays were created using `fetchArray`.

Because these errors only arose after I created `fetchArray`, it's probably an error with that function, but I'm not sure what to try to fix this.

Comment: _“because I do not use `'use strict';` anywhere in my JavaScript file”_ — Modules are strict by default. Aside: your HTML declaration is wrong. [Validate your HTML](//validator.nu).

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre]? Surely you don’t need 238 lines to reproduce this one error.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you're right I was getting an error from a missing semicolon

Comment: @SebastianSimon Fixed validation. I will try to streamline to provide you a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Wait a minute… `emotionsArray[i]` is a string. You can’t shuffle a string; that’s what’s causing the error. Local Storage can only store strings; you need to serialize and parse your array as JSON if you want to store it there.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I trimmed it down to 58 lines of code that I think is all relevant to this issue.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Never messed with JSON before. I'll take a look into it. Thanks for your help!